# Dictionary comprehension issue for python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6, dictionary-comprehension

I have this line of code:

```
d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.iteritems()}}
```

Unfortunately I'm working on python 2.6 and it does not support dictionary comprehensions.

How should it look to make it work for python 2.6?

Comment: Just make that the second element in each tuple

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out. I realized that I forgot to replace `:` with `,`.